# How can I solve err_unknown_url_scheme?

Tags: android, android-webview

## MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.neermaicom;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import static android.content.Intent.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // this will load site in our app
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.neermai.com");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

//This method require to use back button if want to go previous web page

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

This is my code right now. Working fine. But only issue when i share the post by click social medias. It’s says net: err_unknown_url_scheme. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`HTML` links that starts with mailto:, whatsapp: not starts with `"http://"` or `"https://"`, so WebView cannot parse it to right place, we should use intent to redirect the url.

So `setWebViewClient` to your WebView, like below and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url == null || url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) return false;

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    });
```

And you are good to go.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I paste this code. Intent is indicates as a Red. If possible please help me how to enter this code step by step. Coz I have no knowledge about java.

Comment: remove this line "webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());"  from your . code and paste my code just above the line webView.loadUrl("http://www.neermai.com");

and you are done.

Comment: When I try to copy your code as your guide
Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading Exception:" + e);
Log & TAG getting Red (Error). So how to solve it?

Comment: @GobiKrishna I have updated the code .. Now you can try again. It should work now

Comment: This will open it's related app ?

Comment: It's works. Thanks a lot. But still issue with FB like button. FB share is fine.

Comment: When I press FB share button. Screen is going white and left top corner I can see only number 1

Comment: Is there any solution to make work FB like button and comment. Coz it's also available on website. Also print button not working. Help ?

Comment: can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1Q3K2vqFQKY5FuJlQA_sNsoCEuJswAPvk

Comment: Please check above Google drive link for screen shot

Comment: Possible? Just FB like button and Comment box are issue. I shared screen shot above. When I print button, no action.

Comment: do you have any logcat for that?

Comment: That mean ? Please explain... I didn't get?

Comment: you have any logs so that I can understand the issue with FB like better?

Comment: Brother. I made this website with WordPress and it's a plug-in install to like and comment Directly to every post. When I try to share something on FB. It's working. When I press like or comment. It's asking FB username and password. Then it's return to post page. Again when I press like or comment. As per screen shot white page left top of the corner I can see only number 1. Again when I press back button it's return to post page. I have no idea what is logs. I explained here clearly I guess. If you help me in this case. It will be much better to build a Android App. I'm waiting for you.

Comment: I want to build a Android App as soon as possible brother. If you help me. I can start splash screen for my App and next horizontal loading bar. Then should upload in Google store. M still waiting for FB like and comment issue then Splash screen and loading bar -   https://stackoverflow.com/q/60140856/12854586 No reply so waiting. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Also I have uploaded to Google drive, my App. Please install to your phone and try you will understand my issue. Same Google drive. Where I shared screen shot.